# How to convert any Num value to a Floating value in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, numbers

I would like to use functions (for example exponential functions), which only works on Floating types. My input can be any type of Num: Integer, Float, Fractional ...

How is it possible to convert all of them to a Floating?

```
numToFloating :: (Num a, Floating b) => a -> b
...
```

I have no idea, where to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot.  The following is a valid specialization

```
numToFloating :: Complex Float -> Float
```

since [`Complex`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Complex.html#t:Complex)`Float` is an [instance of `Num`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/Data.Complex.html#line-118).  What are we supposed to do with the imaginary part?

So what you really want to say is that the input is any [`Real`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Real) type, giving the signature

```
:: (Real a, Floating b) => a -> b
```

which turns out to be a little stronger than necessary.  There is already [`realToFrac`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:realToFrac)

```
realToFrac :: (Real a, Fractional b) => a -> b
```

which will do what you need, since any [`Floating`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Floating) type is already [`Fractional`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Fractional).